# error fscanf (fichero, "%lf", &nota[i]); ^ Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, array

En un fichero tenemos las notas de un grupo de alumnos de una clase con valores `Nota(1), Nota(2),..., Nota(n – 1)`, establecidas entre 0 y 10. El último dato es un señalero con valor `–50`.

El número de notas que contiene el fichero no se conoce, pero se sabe que el mínimo número de alumnos en la clase es 1 y el máximo 100. Se desea crear un programa que determine la nota media.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define Alumnos 100

    int main() 
    {
    
    int i=0;
    float suma = 0; 
    float media = 0;
    float nota[Alumnos];
    FILE* fichero;
    
    fichero = fopen("notas.dat", "rt");
    
    fscanf (fichero, "%lf", &nota[i]);
    do {         
        suma = suma + nota[i];
        i = i+1; 
        fscanf (fichero, "%lf", &nota[i]);
      } 
       while (nota[i]!=-50);
    
      fclose(fichero);
    
    media = suma/i;
    printf ("El promedio es %lf", media);
    
    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: no puedo hacerlo correr en c++

Comment: Sale algún error? Por favor, edita tu pregunta e incluye cualquier error que estés encontrando

Comment: A que te refieres cuando dices *"no puedo hacerlo
correr en c++"*? No te compila? Tienes que usar
elementos de c++ como `std::array` y `std::ifstream`
y no sabes como?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Exacto no puedo compilar en C++

Comment: Si no puedes compilar .... ¿Cómo es que obtienes el error del título?

Answer (score 0):

La variable `nota[i]` es float, por lo cual hay que usar `"%f"` en `fscanf`. `"%lf"` es para variables `double`